# DatePicker do not show full month name at top because of style inheritance

Tags: wpf, datepicker, styles, controltemplate, basedon

I have a situation where i have to display the DatePicker , The problem is i am not able to see the complete month name at top, i am just able to see the first digit of december
with dots after like "D.." whereas there is enough space to show entire month name. Its because it is inheriting many style of textbox/textblock from controltemplate which i am not including.

[image]

Here is my try :

```
<DatePicker  
  FontSize="6"
  SelectedDate="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}" 
  HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
</DatePicker>

<Style  TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}" >
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <TextBox
                    x:Name="PART_TextBox"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalContentAlignment="Center"                       
                    Text="{Binding Path=SelectedDate, ConverterCulture={x:Static glob:CultureInfo.InvariantCulture}, StringFormat={}{0:yyyy-MM-dd}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DatePicker}}}" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
</Style>
    <Style  TargetType="{x:Type DatePicker}">            
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource FlowWhiteBrush}" />
</Style>
```

How to fix it such that we override the previous style by rewriting in the template written above and make it's alignment in left so that all month appears? But which styles and properties to be overridden?

Comment: Copy/Paste of your code shows the date picker correctly on my end. Must be some other settings on your end...

Comment: Its a style issue then  for sure, Don't know how to fix it,  such that no style will be applied to it other than the few we wrote here.

Comment: HERE: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/datepicker-styles-and-templates  You have the complete DatePicker, and DatePickerCalendar item template. Copy it to your view, and modify it as you wish

Comment: Any other option rather than copying and pasting entire template? As we know it's just the part at the top where we see the month name has to be align left ? If yes , then please write below so that i would be able to mark you as answer.

Comment: If your problem cannot be reproduced, then there is no answer to the question. I can only give you suggestions. I would suggest you to start a total new solution with a project, and only add the DatePicker. if your issue persist then it might be some system settings, otherwise you have to inspect your solution to find where the problem is